# How to set TopLevelDestination in AppBarConfiguration when build a graph programmatically using the Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I build a graph programmatically using the Kotlin DSL.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.addGraph(resources: Resources) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = NavigationGraphRoute.LoginFragment.buildFullPath(),
        route = NavigationGraphRoute.NavGraph.buildFullPath()
    ) {
        addDestinations(resources)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addDestinations(resources: Resources) {
    fragment<SignInFragment>(
        route = NavigationGraphRoute.LoginFragment.buildFullPath()
    ) {

        label = resources.getString(R.string.login_fragment_label)
    }

    fragment<HomeFragment>(
        route = NavigationGraphRoute.HomeFragment.buildFullPath()
    ) {

        label = resources.getString(R.string.home_label)
    }
```

And in **MainActiivty.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


  private lateinit var navController: NavController
  private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

         setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarMain)
         supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
         supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
         supportActionBar?.title = ""

          val toggle =
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(
             this,
             binding.drawerLayout,
             binding.toolbarMain,
             R.string.open,
             R.string.close
            )

          binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
          toggle.syncState()
          val navHostFragment =
              supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
          navController = navHostFragment.navController
          navController.createGraph(
              startDestination = NavigationGraphRoute.LoginFragment.buildFullPath()
          ) {
               addAuthGraph(resources = resources)
          }

          appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, binding.drawerLayout)
          NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbarMain, navController,   appBarConfiguration)
  }
}
```

and in **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/greys_white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar_main"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Custom Navigation Drawer Start -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So the question is, how can I set the top-level destination for `HomeFragment` in `AppBarConfiguration`

Currently it setted like `appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, binding.drawerLayout)`

So, how can I set `appBarConfiguration` in such a way where I can set HomeFragment as TopLevelDestination. The reason why i needed as top is on the HomeFragment I need to see the Hamburger menu in toolbar and on another fragment it should show back. As I using Single Activity Architecture.

Comment: The DSL is nice but soooo little documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can get navdestination ids from graph you created.

```
val graph = navController.createGraph(...)
navController.graph = graph

//Get TopLevelDestination Ids
val topLevelIds = graph.filter {
    it.route == "yourRouteName"
}.map{ it.id }

val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinationIds = topLevelIds.toSet())
    .setOpenableLayout(binding.drawerLayout)
    .build()

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.toolbarMain, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```